# Call a child component function from parent class in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have some issues while calling save button in parent class to call method 
    save in child class. I need to find a solution to call save function from 
    parent component

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
 render(){
  return(
   <Child />
   <button onClick={Child.alert()}>save</button>
  **// this button should call alert function now.**
  )
}
}
export default Parent

// child component
class Child extends React.Component{
 alert= () => {
  console.log('child's alert called')
 }
render(){
  return(
   <button onClick={this.alert()}>Save</button>  
  **// this is calling alert right now**
   )
 }
}
export default Child

**//when save button of the parent class called, it should call the alert 
method in the child class.**
```

Comment: @Shubham, in the original question there is a requirement that no refactoring with passing handling of data should be made, maybe in the current question it is possible to just lift up the `save` method to the parent, pass it as `props` to the child and not even use `refs`?

Comment: @margaretkru, yes that is possible, however the OP hasn't mentioned any information in the question that could help us reach any conclusion. The linked questions answers what the OP has asked

Comment: someone new to `react` might not be aware of possible ways to achieve what he/she wants, and in the described situation I wouldn't recommend using `refs` if it is possible to move the `save` method into the parent component. @Shubham, what is your opinion?

Comment: @margaretkru, In a lot of situation it is possible to lift the state up and manage by passing handlers to the children, I would recommend OP to go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594900/reactjs-lifting-state-up-vs-keeping-a-local-state/47349693#47349693 and see what fits his needs, lifting the state up or calling a child component method

Comment: yes, that's a good resource to read up a bit. I made a quick example on how the components in the current question can be organized to achieve what is asked, in case you are interested, @Anon. Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/03l18p9k2p).

Comment: Hi
I have tried the refs method already. It's not working. and yes I'm quite new to react,

I actually have few child components saving different data with different save buttons nested there only, now I need to make a common save button on parent that will call all the save methods inside the child component, and I cannot move the save calls from child to parent since they are working individually

Comment: And I don't really want to use the redux store for the same, I mean it's the last resort if nothing works

Comment: @Div, could you edit your question with more details and also providing more of your code so that we can better understand the problem you are facing?