# passing data between two child component without shifting up state

Tags: reactjs, state

I am working on the interface with react. As soon as a button in the 'Buttons' area is clicked, the expression in the 'filter text input' must be used to query a REST interface which returns a list of items as JSON. This data must be passed to the lower left panel to update a tree view.
The 'filter text input'+'Buttons' is a controlled input.

```
+-------------------------------------+
| +-------------------------+-------+ |
| | filter text input       |Buttons| |
| +-------------------------+-------+ |
+----------+--------------------------+
| + item1  | +---------------+        |
| |  +-... | | text input    |        |
| + item2  | +---------------+        |
| |  +-... | +---------------+        |
| + item3  | | text input    |        |
| |  +-... | +---------------+        |
| + item4  |                          |
| |  +-... | ...                      |
+----------|--------------------------+
```

The canonical approach according to all the tutorials and documentation is to shift the state up to the common parent. However, this is a pretty bad idea because with every single key stroke the whole view will be updated entirely, including the tree in the left panel.
Is there a generally accepted way (and good practice) to exchange data between components that belong to the same parent without shifting the state upwards or is there any other approach?

Comment: checkout `redux` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w-oQ-i1XB8

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594900/reactjs-lifting-state-up-vs-keeping-a-local-state/47349693#47349693

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. Stick with the current approach (which sounds legitimate and straightforward), but utilize `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent unnecessary updates.
2. Use a central data store. Check out [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly put your code together, there should be no performance concern here, and no need to use a centralized data store such as Redux.

```
However, this is a pretty bad idea because with every single key stroke the whole view will be updated entirely, including the tree in the left panel
```

Have you tried? If the rest of your tree does not change, React will realise this when traversing the two virtual DOM trees for changes, and will not re-render what has not changed. Unless you are incorrectly using the `key` prop and forcing a re-render, this will not happen, as the sub-trees are all the same.

It is true, however, that the `render` method is being called on all of those sub-components. The best way to prevent this, as mentioned by Or B, is to use `shouldComponentUpdate`; something like the following:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.propA !== nextProps.propA) {
    return true; // re-render
  }
  return false; // don't re-render
}
```

You can do a full-scale check quite easily using the `PureComponent` class, like so:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class MyClass extends PureComponent {
  ...
```

This does a shallow check of all of the props being passed to the component. The same functionality can be achieved using the `pure` method of `recompose`, like so:

```
import { pure } from 'recompose';

class MyClass extends Component {
  ...
}

export default pure(MyClass); // same thing, really; just a bit more overhead
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with the way you pass callbacks. If you pass them as arrow functions a different callback is created each time the component is rendered. From the documentation: "However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem." See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html for more details.