# How to access to state of repeated component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to reactjs. I want to access state of a repeated react component. My code is

```
{Object.keys(this.state.sharing).map((share)=>{              
                          return(<Sharings />)
                                               })}
```

above component is repeated 3 times

The Sharing Component contains radio buttons and button.
When the radio button is clicked then only button is enabled.
Here is my code

```
<div className="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <div className="book-now-card p-b-10" style={{height:height}}>
                    <div className="single-sharing" style={{height: '180px'}}>
                        <h3 className="single-sharing-heading">{props.heading}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="m-t-20">
                        {
                            props.rent.map((rent)=>{
                                return(
                                    <div className="m-10" key={rent}>
                                        <input type="radio" name={'radio'} className="m-l-20 " onClick={(e)=>{this.handleChange(rent,e)}} /> <span className="m-l-20" style={{color:'#009688'}}>₹ {rent}</span>
                                        <p className="m-l-55 f-s-12" style={{color: '#65747a'}}>{props.details}</p>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="m-20">
                        <button className="btn btn-secondary col-6 select-rent" disabled={true} onClick={(e)=>{this.proceed(e)}} id={'Button'+this.props.num}>SELECT</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want disable button in button in 1st and 3rd sharing component when radio button in 2nd sharing Component is clicked. I tried DOM manipulation with document.getElementById but click function in button stopped working.

Comment: You must update the parent component state when clicking the radio. This is the easiest way to update siblings.

Comment: The easiest way to handle it is to keep the state shared between components in the Parent, Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594900/reactjs-lifting-state-up-vs-keeping-a-local-state/47349693#47349693 and https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Thanks it worked @IlyaNovojilov

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` component should be [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

In your `map` method you should have something like this:

```
<input
  type="radio"
  name={'radio'}
  className="m-l-20 "
  value={this.state.radiosValues[index]} {/* get radio value from state */}
  onClick={()=>{ // We don't need event because we work with booleans
    const radiosValues = this.state.radiosValues
    radiosValues[index] = !radiosValues[index] // If true we want false, if false we want true
    this.setState({ radioValues})
 }}
/>
```