# Updating state from prop update will cause loop error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, setstate

I want to update state with value I'm getting from child component but for some strange reason I will get loop error if I'm using `setstate` in my method. Here is my code snippet:

```
class ParentTab extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayVal : '0',
    };
  }

  totalRec = value => {
    console.log('value', value); // will show the value '2' after getting it from ChildTab component 
    if (value) {
      // will cause infinite loop error
      this.setState({
        displayVal: value.toString(),
      });
    }
}

  render() {
    console.log('totalRec', this.totalRec()); // will show undefined because there is delay in getting the value.
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildTab totalRow={this.totalRec} {...this.props} />
        />
        Value: {this.state.displayVal} // will show undefined
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`ChildTab` component will be getting value from database so there will be delay. Whole page will be render first and so `this.totalRec()` is undefined. That's why I want to use `state` to rerender it.

However if `totalRec()` method is triggered, I will be getting `react` loop error when I try to use `this.setState` in `totalRec()` method.

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have loaded data from child component `ChildTab`,then why u doing state  lifting to `ParentTab`  updating state which causing loop error?Why u dont want to load data from parent then passed to Child?

Comment: I need to show updated value at `ParentTab`

Comment: thats what ,you can load value from Parent instead Child.Isn't it. please see my 2nd quetition in above comment

Comment: Can you post the code for `ChildTab` as well.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594900/reactjs-lifting-state-up-vs-keeping-a-local-state/47349693#47349693 to understand better about structuring your code

Comment: you're correct. Instead of querying db in child component, I now did the query at parent and pass the result to child. Thank you for all your input. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. To break the loop, you can simple return `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` when `this.state.displayVal === nextState.displayVal` or more appropriate condition based on your problem. Refer to: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate
2. Another problem could be `setState` will not fire immediately, so any code depends on `state` might use the old value if you call it after `setState`. The solution is to write `async` function and `await this.setState({...});`. Refer to: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate
3. The `props` passed into child component should be read-only. Do not change them in child component.