# How to send value from child component to parent?(functional components)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a parent called `main_homepageComponent` and two child `search_barComponent` & `Iteams_Component`

I want to do something like this:-

When a user puts some text in `search-box`(input text) of `search_barComponent` I want to hide `Iteams_Component`

Hierarchy:-

```
--main_homepageComponent
  --search_barComponent
  --Iteams_Component
```

Currently, I am trying to create a state variable in my `search_barComponent`, and when the user input some text then:-

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')  //extra code removed
onChangeText={(text) => {setSearch(text)}}
```

and in my `main_homepageComponent` I added something like this:-

```
 const [search, setSearch] = useState('') //extra code removed
  <ScrollView style={{ height: windowHeight }}>
                        {search.length < 1 ? (
                            <View>
                                <ItemsComponent></ItemsComponent>
                            </View>
                        ) : null}
                    </ScrollView>
```

But I do not know how can I send back the `search` value from `search_barComponent` to `main_homepageComponent` so I can run

```
            {search.length < 1 ? (
                            <View>
                                <ItemsComponent></ItemsComponent>
                            </View>
                        ) : null}
                    </ScrollView>
```

this and hide `Iteams_Component` when user input text in searchbox.

Please provide an answer for `functional components` because I do not understand the `class component` much

This is my app image:-

[image: app Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - Lifting state up vs keeping a local state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594900/reactjs-lifting-state-up-vs-keeping-a-local-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a `search` and `setSearch` state in each component, just create one in parent component and send them as props to children.
in main_homepageComponent when you want to add child components...

```
<Search_barComponent search={search} setSearch={setSearch}/>
<Iteams_Component search={search} setSearch={setSearch}/>
```

and in the child components just use `props.search` and `props.setSearch` instead of creating them again.

there's a rule in react you always have to keep in mind: "single source of truth, not more" bring your state in hierarchy high up enough so every child depends on a single source of truth...

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Child (props) {
  const [ name, setName ] = React.useState({someDefault:1})

useEffect(()=>{
    props.onChange(name);
  },[name]);

 return (
   <div>
     <input name="name" 
            onChange={e=>setName({...name, name:e.target.value})}
     />
   </div>
  )

}




export default function Parent () {
    const [ name, setName ] = React.useState({})
  
    const  handleChange = (newValue) =>{
        setName(newValue);
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Child value={name} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```